# How to search in nested JSON data in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, json, search, filter, vuejs2

I have nested JSON data like:

```
[{"id":"1","province_id":"ABC","name":"City One"},{"id":"2","province_id":"EFG","name":"City Two"}]
```

I want to filter the JSON by `province_id` and put it in another variable. Is there any solutions in VueJS such as `Vue.filter();` ?
I know we have "linq" which does the job but I do not want to use it.

Comment: Can't you just set that to a variable, then loop over it looking at the providence_id property? var yourQuestionCode = [{"province_id":1}]; yourQuestionCode[0].province_id

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what you're looking for is the javascript Array's filter() function. You should definitely spend some time getting familiar with filter, along with others like map and reduce. It'll make slicing and dicing your data much easier.

```
var serializedData = `[{"id":"1","province_id":"ABC","name":"City One"},{"id":"2","province_id":"EFG","name":"City Two"}]`;
var data = JSON.parse(serializedData);

var provinceAbc = data.filter(d => d.province_id === 'ABC');
```

That line will get you all objects where its province_id is "ABC"

Also, since you mentioned "linq" in your post, filter() is like IEnumerable.Where(), and map() is like IEnumerable.Select() in .NET Linq terms

Comment: Thanks for your answer.The "linq" I have mentioned is js implementation of it [link](https://github.com/mihaifm/linq)

Answer (score 2):

I think this will work for you:

```js
var nestedJson = `[{"id":"1","province_id":"ABC","name":"City One"},{"id":"2","province_id":"EFG","name":"City Two"}]`;
var array = JSON.parse(nestedJson);

array = array.map(e => e["province_id"]);

console.log(array);
```

Comment: this is technically incorrect, as it'll return a list of objects that contain only the province_id, as opposed to returning a list of the full objects that match the specified id

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I want to select all the objects in the JSON where their `province_id` is equal to `'ABC'` for example.